# Heavy Duty use of SQL Compact with WebMatrix

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I've been told not to use SQL Server Compact that comes with WebMatrix for any heavy duty stuff. But, just exactly how heavy is "heavy duty"?

If I have a couple thousand products in a SQL Server Compact DB, plus a couple tables for registration and a couple tables for random stuff, would that be okay? Will SQL Server Compact be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Your description of usage suggests that SQL Server Compact 4 would be sufficient for your usage. Your scenario is generally the reason SQL Compact was created. If you don't already have a full SQL Server instance at the ready, then consider choosing the SQL Compact solution.

It sounds like the advice given was focused on 'heavy-duty'. I'd consider heavy-duty to be sustained reads and writes, or requiring features not in SQL Compact: stored procedures, procedural TSQL, replication. See more on [feature sets of SQL CE 4 & SQL Server 2008](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html). Obvious advice would be to pick the engine that your web app needs.

The great thing about SQL Compact is that you can scale up/migrate to a SQL Server instance without much effort if/when your requirements change.